# Prevent too many hyphens in a row

Tags: hyphenation

I would like to set things up that there are never more then three hyphenated lines in a row. Is there a command or parameter for this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How often does this happen to you? I suspect long words and narrow columns. Perhaps rewording when you proofread is the best solution. A MWE would help.

Comment: There is a parameter `\doublehyphendemerits` for not three, but two consecutive hyphenated lines. Demerits are badness squared; the default, at least in plain, is `10 000`.